# How to change initial commit of branch after filter-branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

After a `filter-branch` on `master` (to add sign-off), I have this :

```
A-B-C-D-E-F (master)

A'-X-Y-Z (branch xxx)
```

where A' is the old initial commit. I want to "reconnect" my branch "xxx" to master, to initial commit `A` to have something like this :

```
A-B-C-D-E-F (master)
 \
  X-Y-Z (branch xxx)
```

How to do that ? 
Thanks

Comment: You mean A and A' does not have any common ancestor?

Comment: `A'` is the old first commit, but after applying `filter-branch` on all `master`, `A` has changed, so that the branch `xxx` is no more starting from `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3-steps solution with backup option included :

```
# create a backup for the branch
git checkout -b backup-xxx xxx

# force position of branch xxx at A
git branch -f xxx A

# get the commits you wanted from the backup branch
git checkout xxx
git cherry-pick X Y Z
```

You'll have `backup-xxx` in the state xxx was before the operations, just in case you regret your move later.

Backup plan :

```
# to restore branch xxx in its previous state
git branch -f xxx backup-xxx
```

Comment: Thanks ! Just a change, before doing `git cherry-pick`, I had to `checkout` (back) to xxx. And after, I have done `push -f` to update remote branch. Great ! Thanks !

Comment: @xnopre Hey you're right! I forgot to change back to your branch. Good point, I've edited.

Comment: Or else we could have done `git checkout -B xxx A` at second step and not have to checkout back to `xxx`. Just a thought

Comment: You have to be on `xxx` to do `cherry-pick`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps.

```
git checkout master
git checkout <SHA-HASH-OF-A-AFTER-FILTER-BRANCH> #Now your head should be in detached state at commit-hash of A
git checkout -b <NewConnectedBranch> #B is created from A commit
git cherry-pick X..Z #Applying changes from the disconnected branch
```

Comment: How is this affecting branch `xxx`?

Comment: If this works, he can delete xxx and and rename the "NewConnectedBranch" to xxx or he can continue

Comment: Also, I agree it does not reconnect. It simply involves creating another connected branch. Would solve his issue anyway.